# This installation of MySQL is already upgraded to 5.7.25?

Tags: mysql, sudo, ubuntu-18.04, dpkg

I used *sudo apt upgrade* and got this:

```
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
```

So I did it and I see this for more than an hour.

```
Setting up mysql-server-5.7 (5.7.25-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) ...
Checking if update is needed.
This installation of MySQL is already upgraded to 5.7.25, use --force if you still need to run mysql_upgrade
```

Nothing happens. I have not used MySQL for a long time and don't know what should I do. Understand there must be something with *force* but I am new with Ubuntu and not so familiar with commands. Can you help me? I don't understand nor what the problem is...

EDIT: I can use MySQL Workbench and get access in Terminal too, but still keep seeing that error

Comment: Hello @Nicole, did you managee to fix this error? I've got exactly the same problem: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1117968/cant-get-back-to-a-stable-apt-state

Comment: @COil Hello, I didn't fix it and than removed it completely it because I couldn't do anything. Is your error gone? Thank you for trying to help, I'll see your answer :)

Comment: This here solved it for me:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/258939/200362